# Set theory, seems like a difficult question (Choice Function)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

So, I don't know if this certain type of set has a name in English. If it has, I'll be glad if someone will edit my post.

**Definition**: Let $A$ be a set and $f: P(A)\setminus \emptyset \rightarrow A$ a choice function. A well-ordered set $(B,R)$ is called *proper* if $B \subseteq A$ and for every $b \in B: f(A\setminus B_b)=b $. ($B_b$ is the initial segment with $b$ being upper bound)

**Question:** Let there be $\mathbb N$ and $S=P(\mathbb N)\setminus \emptyset$.

We'll define a choice function  $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb N$ as following: For every finite set $X$, $f(X)=max(X)$, that is - maximal value with regular $<$ relation on $\mathbb N$. For every infinite set $X$, $f(X)$ is the 10th element of the set (10th according with the regular $<$ relation on $\mathbb N$).

Find the proper subsets and what's the order on $\mathbb N$ you get as a result.

I tried solving this for a very long time. Any full solution would be very appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering that you get is

$$9<10<11<\cdots 8<7<6<5<4<3<2<1<0$$
the proper sets are just the initial segments.

This is obtained as follows 
 $$f(\mathbb{N})=9$$
 $$f(\mathbb{N} - \{9\})=10$$
 $$f(\mathbb{N} - \{9,10\})=11$$
etc
 $$f(\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\})=8$$
$$f(\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\})=7$$
and so on.

Comment: Why isn't it $10<11<12<13<... <9<8<7<6<5<4<3<2<1?$

Comment: Maybe dosent $\mathbb{N}$ start with $0$ and have $9$ as its tenth element ?

Comment: Well then it depends on what you define $\mathbb N$ as. But can you explain (or edit your post) how you reached your answer about the order?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ always starts with $0$, I edited hope its clear whats happening.